# How to use imported library in app.js in another script file?

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-9

I'm currently using Laravel Framework 9.48.0 which comes with vite as the default assets bundler.

I installed moment.js with npm command:

```
npm install moment --save
```

then I imported the moment library in app.js like this:

```
import moment from 'moment/moment';
```

I can use it inside app.js with no problems, but when I try to access it in another script it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
```

I'm new in laravel and I don't know much about how vite works, can any one help me please??

Just for reference, this is my **vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Http/Livewire/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

this is my **package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@alpinejs/focus": "^3.10.5",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.0.6",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "moment": "^2.29.4"
    }
}
```

this is my **app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
import focus from '@alpinejs/focus';
import moment from 'moment/moment';
window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.plugin(focus);

Alpine.start();

console.log(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')); // works fine in here only
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. Until a solution is found, my workaround has been to insert the necessary libraries that would otherwise be integrated through npm installs / calling through app.js, through inline script tags

```
        <x-slot name="form">
            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                {{-- Resumable.js --}}
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/resumablejs@1.1.0/resumable.js"></script>
                <div class="mt-2 ">
                    <h1>Video</h1>
                    <div id="resumable-error" style="display: none">
                        Resumable not supported
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="border-2 bg-charon-100 hover:bg-charon-200 py-4 px-12" id="resumable-browse" data-url="{{ url('upload-video') }}">
                        <div id="resumable-drop" style="display: none">
                            <p>Click to Browse Files<br>or drop here</p>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                    <ul id="file-upload-list" class="list-unstyled"  style="display: none">
                    </ul>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </x-slot>
```

in this example, resumable.js requires jquery to operate and try as I might, I have been completely unable to find a proper solution. quite frankly, I've been pulling my hair out.